# C windows _popen on command that request input: avoid freeze

Tags: c, windows, popen, freeze

I have this problem;
I'm writing a C-coded server that have to execute cmd command. The main() has to create a new thread and this thread has to create a new process that have to start this cmd command and send back the results.

This works fine if the command sends back only output (i.e. dir, netstat, ls etc). But when I try to use a command that has ro wait for an input as "date" (that wait for a new date) the new process freeze. This is not possible to solve because I can use WaitForSingleObject on the new process' handle and use a timeout so if the process doesn't finish for a while, I can terminate it using TerminateProcess().

But using process cmd.exe will continue running because it was started by the process of my server and never closed.

I don't care about command that requires input, I just want to ignore them so that if the _popen wait for something I simply close the cmd and return.

Is there are some way to avoid this situation where _popen freeze on a command that require inputs?

Here the code of the process that runs _popen

```
char readBuff[8096];
DWORD readed;
ReadFile(pipe,readBuff,8096,&readed,NULL);
FILE * out=_popen(commandToExec,"r"); //assume commandToExec contains "date" 
char buffer[128];
char output[8096];
output[0]='\0';
while(fgets(buffer, 128, out)){
    snprintf(output,8096,"%s%s\n",outputComando,buffer);
}
DWORD writed;
WriteFile(pipe,outputComando,8096,&scritti,NULL); //it writes the output to a pipe
```

This works fine on an output-only command but it never reaches the "while" on a command that requires an input (I debugged it)

Answer (score 1):

According to the msdn page on popen, you need extra work to redirect both stdin and stout

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499.aspx